# Is there a term for min + (max - min) / 2?

Tags: r

I'm looking for a function to do that in R. I know how to write that function. Just don't want to reinvent something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

min + (max - min) / 2 = (min + max) / 2
It's called the [mid-range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-range). I don't know of an existing function in R.

Comment: I guess sum(range(your_variable))/2 should do the trick

Comment: Or, as @Konrad notes, `mean(range(x))`

Answer (score 3):

Isn’t `mean` what you want?

```
> mean(c(5, 11))
8
```

Note that the result of course differs as soon as you have a range with more than two values. I’m assuming that you only have *two* values, `min` and `max`.

If you’ve got a vector of more than two values, use `range` to get their minimum and maximum:

```
> x = 1 : 100
> mean(range(x))
50.5
```

Comment: Konrad, this fails for asymmetric samples or distributions. Try `mean(c(5, 10, 11))` which give 8 2/3 yet the range-based result is the based.

Comment: Though you could use `mean(range(x))`

Comment: Indeed, good point.

Comment: @Dirk That’s why I explicitly wrote that it only works for *two* values, not more. That said, I still believe that what the OP searches for is (by definition) the mean of two numbers. But I like the `range` version …